# Setting fixed length with python

Tags: python

I have str that are like '60' or '100'.
I need the str to be '00060' and '00100',

How can i do this? 
code is something like this:
I was using  '0'+'0'+'0' as plug. now need to fix
d==0006000100

```
  a4 ='60'
  a5 ='100'

  d=('0'+'0'+'0'+a4+'0'+'0'+a5)
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since you are manipulating strings, [str.zfill()](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill) does exactly what you want.

```
>>> s1, s2 = '60', '100'
>>> print s1.zfill(5), s2.zfill(5)
00060 00100
```

Answer (score 10):

Like this:

```
num = 60 
formatted_num = u'%05d' % num
```

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting) for more information about formatting numbers as strings.

If your number is already a string (as your updated question indicates), you can pad it with zeros to the right width using the `rjust` string method:

```
num = u'60'
formatted_num = num.rjust(5, u'0')
```

Comment: it comes as '60' i am combining example 0006000100,

Comment: @user: OK, it seems like Wang's answer (using `zfill`) is the way to go in your case since it's built for exactly the type of thing you're doing

Comment: From http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html: "the % operator is still supported; it will be deprecated in Python 3.1 and removed from the language at some later time.". Use `"".format()` instead for future compatibility: `u"{0:0>5d}".format(60)` or `u"{0:0>5s}".format(str(60))`.

Comment: I just discovered you can use !s in the format string to force string conversion, so you need only a single case to handle both 60 and '60': `"{0!s:0>5s}".format(60)`

Answer (score 2):

If "60" is already a string, you have to convert it to  a number before applying the formatting. The most practical one works just like C's printf:

```
a  ="60"
b = "%05d" % int(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading your favorite Python documentation appreciated:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

"""

If the width field is preceded by a zero ('0') character, this enables zero-padding. This is equivalent to an alignment type of '=' and a fill character of '0'.
"""

Answer (score 0):

If it's already a string you might want to use the .zfill() method.

```
myval.fill(5)
```