# Python fixed width strings with the Template object

Tags: python

Is there a way make fixed width substitutions with the python String.Template objects substitution language

For example if I wanted s to be 'A string 0003' how would I modify this code:

```
from string import Template
stmpl=Template("A string ${tcount}")
s=stmpl.substitute(tcount=3)
print(s)
```

Related question, not using template strings:
[Setting fixed length with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138062/setting-fixed-length-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read throu [PEP 292](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0292/) , "Simpler String Substitutions" does not make it as expressive as % format. i think you had to format the substitution yourself before feed to the template. something like

```
"{0:05}".format(3)
```

Answer (score 0):

[`s=stmpl.substitute(tcount=str(3).zfill(4))`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.zfill)